# PDF to text in R in Mac

Tags: r, tm, pdftotext

I have downloaded PDFtoText in mac and wrote following code to convert pdf files to text:

```
pdf_to_load =("~/my_directory/my.pdf")
system(paste('pdftotext', pdf_to_load))
```

The code runs well but I am not able to see my.txt in the source directory nor it has been saved anywhere in the folders. Where I went wrong?

One of my mentors were able to run the same code in his computer and he was able to see the converted .txt file.

Kindly guide.

Comment: I installed the pdftotext and pdfinfo both. But it does not read pdfinfo.

Comment: > file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext")))
[1] FALSE  TRUE

Answer (score 5):

You get a wrong result if the default PDF extraction engine is not found on your computer, see `?tm::readPDF`. Those engines are not part of R or of the `tm` package, and it depends on your computer whether the necessary programs are already installed.

The easiest solution is to install the programs `pdftotext` and `pdfinfo` (you'll need both), which you can obtain as precompiled binaries [here](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html).

Once these programs are correctly installed, you should be able to extract the text of the PDF file without a system call, by using the `readPDF()` function of the `tm` package

```
library(tm)
my_pdf_txt <- readPDF(control=list(text="-layout"))(elem=list(uri="~/my_directory/my.pdf"), language="en")
```

Comment: > file.exists(Sys.which(c("pdfinfo", "pdftotext")))
[1] FALSE  TRUE   Where I went wrong? The installation of both pdftotext and pdfinfo were successful.

Comment: The error message means that the system cannot find `pdfinfo`. Often this is because the PATH is not set correctly; but I have no experience in Mac systems so I can only refer to the installation guidelines in the webpage that I indicated. 
As a quick fix I suggest that you copy the precompiled binary of `pdfinfo` in your working directory. You can display your working directory in an `R` session with `getwd()`. Hope this helps.